# Build Excel formulas with string replacements

Tags: c#, excel

```
for (long i = 2; i <= numberOfRows; i++)
{
    string quarry =
        "=IF(J"+i+"<10000,J"+i+"*0.05,IF(J"+i+ "<30000,(J" + i + "-10000)*0.1+500,IF(J" + i + "<70000,(J" + i + "-30000)*0.15+2500,IF(J" + i + "<140000,(J" + i + "-70000)*0.2+8500,IF(J" + i + "<250000,(J" + i + "-140000)*0.25+22500,IF(J" + i + "<500000,(J" + i + "-250000)*0.3+50000,IF(J" + i + ">500000,(J" + i + "-500000)*0.32+125000)))))))";
    WS.Cells[i, 11].Formula = quarry;   
}
```

I had originally intended to make this alot neater by adding the base string into a `StringBuilder` and then doing a `string.Replace` call on the column value with the `long` variable `i`, but it did not work saying `i` cannot be converted to char.

Not limited to a string builder, how else can I improve this statement where I could easily change the value of a very long string by replacing the concerned elements?

(i.e: this is a pretty long Excel formula C# query that gets inserted into the worksheet as the `for` loop rolls)

Comment: What happens when `J[i]` is *exactly* `500000`?

Comment: Ah, damn, you're right. Lucky none of this made it to production (yet).

Comment: You should consider splitting up the Excel formula.  Larger Excel formulas have the same problems that larger C# methods have.  They're difficult to maintain.  Can you imagine searching this formula for a missing paranthesis?  An Excel spreadsheet has lots of columns; why not use them?  Store your intermediate results in columns somewhere on your sheet, or on another sheet to hide them.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'm not even going to review the C#, because there's a far better way to do the Excel portion.

Instead of creating this enormous formula (which I hope you don't need anymore nested `IF` portions, you've hit Excel's limit of 7), you can create a table that has the formula properties in it, then lookup what's in that table.

So, let's create our formula table/area:

```
---L---+--M--+---N---
Level  |Rate |Add
      0| 0.05|      0
  10000|  0.1|    500
  30000| 0.15|   2500
  70000|  0.2|   8500
 140000| 0.25|  22500
 250000|  0.3|  50000
 500000| 0.32| 125000
```

So, with that, we can build our *actual* formula:

```
=(J1-INDEX(L:L,MATCH(J1,L:L,1)))*INDEX(M:M,MATCH(J1,L:L,1))+INDEX(N:N,MATCH(J1,L:L,1))
```

If you're not an Excel whiz, here's what's happening:

The `INDEX(...)` function in a formula will do a lookup on the first value in a column that matches a specific location. So, `INDEX(L:L,1)` will return the value in `L1`. Simple enough.

Next, `MATCH(...)` is a function that will find the first value in a column that is less than, equal to or greater than the provided value. So `MATCH(J1,L:L,1)` will find the *index* of the cell that is the last cell found which is less than (the final `1` parameter) our current cell. So from our `L` column, for `1` it finds `0`, etc. It then returns the row that cell is on, which can be piped to `INDEX` to find the actual value in that cell (or *a different* column).

So when we put it together, assuming `J1` is 100000, we're replacing our formula with:

```
=(100000-70000)*0.2+8500
```

Which gives us `14,500`, the exact value your formula gives us.

Some bonuses of this version:

- Shorter, more concise formula. Easy copy/paste, easy to change the values later. (Suppose the criteria for `70000` become `65000`, easy to change.)
- More descriptive information, adding values is a piece of cake (and requires `0` work from the programmer).
- Doesn't require a C# programme to pre-fill the spreadsheet. (That's a huge bonus right there.)
- Makes you look like a boss being able to show the business guys how this stuff works.
- Less typing in the future.

These are not mutually exclusive items.

Comment: This is great, though I can't comment about the accuracy of the code since I definitely do not qualify as an Excel whiz, it's certainly something I've never thought of. Will need some time to digest the info.

Answer (score 8):

Horizontal scroll is evil.

```
for (long i = 2; i <= numberOfRows; i++)
{
    string quarry 
        = "=" 
        + "IF(J" + i + "<10000,"+" J" + i + "*0.05,"
        + "IF(J" + i + "<30000,(J" + i + "-10000)*0.1+500,"
        + "IF(J" + i + "<70000,(J" + i + "-30000)*0.15+2500,"
        + "IF(J" + i + "<140000,(J" + i + "-70000)*0.2+8500,"
        + "IF(J" + i + "<250000,(J" + i + "-140000)*0.25+22500,"
        + "IF(J" + i + "<500000,(J" + i + "-250000)*0.3+50000,"
        + "IF(J" + i + ">500000,(J" + i + "-500000)*0.32+125000"
        + ")))))))"
        ;
    WS.Cells[i, 11].Formula = quarry;   
}
```

Even if you're just trying out an idea don't let code become unreadable.  It only makes it that much harder to spot bugs and make improvements.

Comment: "horizontal scroll is evil" -- your code side-scrolls on my laptop T_T

Comment: @AlexReinking better?

Comment: Your code relieves the horizontal scrolling in the C# code, but not in Excel.  If someone wanted to check out the formula in Excel, they'll be scrolling left and right.